# Rails 6 deploy to Heroku, using bundler 2, but still craches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler, ruby-on-rails-6

I updated from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6.0. The upgrade issues on heroku are known:

[heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues)

Upon deploy:

```
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.1
```

In `Gemfile.lock`: (of course I also updated bundler locally)

```
bundler (2.0.1)
```

in `procfile`

```
web: bundle exec bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
```

Deleted Gemfile.lock and rerun `bundle update` and redeployed to heroku, but still getting this error, *where it says I'm using ruby 2.6.0 : problem is probably here, but don't know how to correct it :*

```
2019-06-03T19:04:00.924967+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
```

In the deploy messages also:

```
2019-06-03T19:04:00.925009+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Heroku indicates: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1563

and in my `Gemfile.lock` I have:

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.1p33

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.1
```

Still, the app crashed on heroku.

Comment: I guess you know that Rails 6 hasn't been released yet (and therefore Rails 6.0 doesn't actually exist)?

Answer (score 1):

Got great support from Heroku on this. I needed to change the name of `procfile` (all lower case) to `Procfile` with capital C.

In addition to the link I gave in my question, have a look here too :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues

Hope this helps,